# What is the best way to populate a listbox after user selects a row in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I just started using ASP.NET MVC about a month ago and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do the following common scenario. I've got a table with summary data and when the user selects a row I want to display the corresponding detail in an adjacent listbox or textbox or whatever. I think I can make it work by adding an action link to each row in the table and doing it all server side but I'm assuming it would be slow since I would have to reload the table each time the user makes a selection. Plus I'd have to figure out how to reset the table to the selected row, correct?

Is there a way to load just the listbox using jquery or javascript or ajax somehow? I'm assuming this is "client-side" programming? Also I'm trying to avoid using stuff like angular or react. I'm trying to hold off until blazor is established so that I won't have to keep learning new stuff.

I not really looking for a complete solution (although that'd be nice), I'd be happy if you could just point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Edit: I found some jquery code that populates a dropdown list based on the selection of another dropdown list. Not sure this is the best way to go or not. Looks complicated.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#Country').change(function () {
                var selectedCountry = $("#Country").val();
                var regionsSelect = $('#Region');
                regionsSelect.empty();
                if (selectedCountry != null && selectedCountry != '') {
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetRegions")', { iso3: 
                    selectedCountry }, function (regions) {
                        if (regions != null && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(regions))
                        {
                            regionsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: null,
                                text: ""
                            }));
                            $.each(regions, function (index, region) {
                                regionsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                                    value: region.Value,
                                    text: region.Text
                                }));
                            });
                        };
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Use a partial view and a little Ajax. It's pretty straight forward. See this tutorial I found, maybe it helps (if not, google "master detail partial view")  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEi1RbxG8ok

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Unfortunately we're blocked form youtube here at work. I'll check it out when I get home but that sounds like a good idea. I found another way using jquery that reloads the element. Not sure which way is best. I'm guessing the partial view is easier but the jquery getJSON method works in more situations (like if you were not using ASP.NET MVC for example)

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing actually - you're using an ajax get (or post if you need) to return the partial view in order to load only parts of the page. It has been used a ton on the mvc sites I've worked on, we always end up blending that.